# Gatsby + Markdown: GraphQL query renders as a component but not when imported into a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I have a simple component that reads an md file and renders the HTML:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data)
  const createMarkup = { __html: data.allMarkdownRemark.edges[0].node.html }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>test start</h1>
      <p>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup} />
      </p>
      <h1>test end</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default IndexPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query MyQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark {
      edges {
        node {
          html
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Works great when accessed like "localhost:8000/components/index_page"

So then I tried to import it into page very simply like this:

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "./components/header"
import Nav from "./components/nav"
import Footer from "./components/footer"
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap"
import IndexPage from "./components/index_page" <----- THIS

export default function PHBOGFC() {
  return (
    <div>
      <IndexPage /> <------ HERE
      <Header />
      <Nav />
      <Container fluid></Container>
      <img
        src="/phbogfc.svg"
        alt="The Preposterously Huge Book of Google Font Combinations"
      />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

But I get this error in the browser, instead of the output I normall get when accessing the component directly:

[image]

What step or command am I missing? If a component renders fine by itself, why would it not render when imported into another page (component)?

Comment: page query works only in ... page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `IndexPage` component, you are using a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/), which only works in a page (hence the name) component.

The only way that component may be rendered at `localhost:8000/components/index_page` is by creating a structure like `/src/pages/components/index_page.js` which is a kind of nonsense, since a the components should be a separate entity. An ideal structure should look like:

```
/
|-- /.cache
|-- /plugins
|-- /public
|-- /src
    |-- /components
    |-- /pages
    |-- /templates
    |-- html.js
|-- /static
|-- gatsby-config.js
|-- gatsby-node.js
|-- gatsby-ssr.js
|-- gatsby-browser.js
```

If you are importing pages in a separate component, you are breaking the page query rule, in that case, you may want to change the structure or using a [`StaticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/) (or `useStaticQuery` hook), which also has some limitations but may work for your use-case.

Comment: I didn't understand the difference between static and page queries but that all makes sense now! Thanks!